# Solenoid's magnetic fields calculated in two different ways don't match

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

It's been a few days now trying to realize how is it possible that calculating the magnetic field exerted by a cylinder of finite length $h$ and radius $R$ very far away in two different ways - one as a superposition of magnetic dipoles and the other by Biot-Savart's law gets me two completely different answers. Shouldn't I get the same answer?

More explicitly, say there is a magnetized cylinder with magnetization density $M=\alpha\hat{z}$. We get a line current density $K = \vec{M}\times{\hat{n}} = \alpha \hat{\varphi}$ meaning there are currents across the surface of the cylinder.
Calculating the total magnetic dipole moment of the cylinder:

$\vec{m}=\int Mdv'=\int_{0}^{h}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\alpha\ R\ d\rho'\ d\varphi'\ dz'\ \hat{z}=2\pi h \alpha R^{2}\hat{z}$

Then the electric field far away is given by:

$\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\frac{3\hat{r}(\hat{r}\cdot\vec{m})-\vec{m}}{r^{3}} = \frac{h\alpha R^{2}\mu_{0}}{2r^{3}}\left(2cos\theta\hat{r}-sin\theta\hat{\theta}\right)$

On the $z$ axis, $\theta = 0$, then:

$\vec{B} = \frac{h\alpha R^{2}\mu_{0}}{z^{3}}\hat{z}$

**However, calculating the magnetic field on a point $z$ on the cylinder's axis using Biot-Savart's law gives the following** :
$\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_{0}\alpha }{2}\left(\frac{z}{\left(R^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}-\frac{z-h}{\left(R^{2}+(z-h)^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)\hat{z}$

Of course that is on a general point and not when $z\gg h, R$ but even when trying to approximate the magnetic field very far away, it doesn't give the previous magnetic field I have found by treating the cylinder like a big magnetic dipole.

**How does that make sense? Have I done something wrong? The results should obviously coincide**

Comment: I've deleted a number of inappropriate comments and/or responses to them.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your first integral: the integrand should be $\alpha\rho'$, not $\alpha R$. This yields $\vec{m}=\pi h\alpha R^2\hat{z}$.

With this correction, far away from the solenoid ($z\gg h$ and $z \gg R $), the magnetic field on the $z$-axis simplifies to
$$\vec{B}=\frac{h\alpha R^2 \mu_0}{2z^3}\hat{z}$$
with both approaches.

Comment: First of all, thank you! I really appreciate it. I still fail to see how the expression I've found using Biot-Savart's law gives me the same answer in the limit $z\gg h,R$, can you tell me what approximations have you done? Thank you again!

Comment: Try applying the binomial approximation.

Comment: I did so on a few instances. I tried first neglecting powers higher than one and then approximating, and tried approximating everything without neglecting first. There are many "small quantities" in the equation, and I do get some answers but not the one I have gotten with the magnetic dipole approach. Could you please specify a bit more?

Comment: Try dividing the numerator and the denominator of the first term by $z$, the second term by $z-h$, then apply the binomial approximation.

Comment: $\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_{0}\alpha }{2}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{R}{z^{2}}^{2}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}-\frac{1}{\left(\frac{R^{2}}{(z-h)^{2}}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)\hat{z} = \vec{B}=\frac{\mu_{0}\alpha }{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{R^{2}}{z^{2}}-(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{R^{2}}{(z-h)^{2}})\right)\hat{z}$ . I don't think I'm getting there. Sorry for being such slow-understanding and thank you again.